# Is there any scenario in which a property can be somehow referenced in the compiled IL?

Tags: c#, .net, types, properties, il

I'm working on modifying an assembly using `Mono.Cecil`, involving integrating code from assembly into another. Part of the problem involves translating incorrect references to various things, such as types and methods, and inserting some member definitions.

My question is whether there is any scenario in which a property itself can be referenced by the IL (as opposed to its accessor methods). In other words, will I ever need to 'fix' references to properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There aren't any instructions that take a property as their operand. You can tell simply from the fact that [`ILGenerator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't have any `Emit(OpCode, PropertyInfo)` overload: that overload would be needed to support such an instruction. Mono Cecil's [`ILProcessor`](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/Mono.Cecil.Cil/ILProcessor.cs) doesn't have any such overload either.

Comment: Yes, I thought so. I was just making sure, so I don't miss any gotchas. Thank you.